# how to select child element with particular class name using jqlite in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

Actually angular js doesn't  recommend using jquery for DOM 
manipulation but it provide basic dom manipulation using jqlite(extended from jquery with limited operation) but if i want to select a child element of target element,it can be easily done using jquery but jqlite doesn't support selector in children() method.. how can i do that using jqlite .

In jquery,this is possible

```
$(this).children('.class_name');
```

But in jqlite this is not possible

```
angular.element(event.target).children('.class_name');
```

Is there any other way doing it?

Comment: Also try .find rather than .children

Comment: find() in jqLite is Limited to lookups by tag name... any other way?

Comment: `element[0].getElementsByClassName('class-name-without-dot')` inside your link function

Answer (score 3):

You can just use querySelector:

```
event.target.querySelector('.class_name');
```

As far as I remember event.target is DOM element and querySelector is widely supported http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector